# Testing for items being held by cursor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using **functions** and **1.14**, I tried testing for a book and quill with nothing typed inside,

```
tag @a[tag=cleanbook] remove cleanbook
```

^ resetting the tag since it's an infinite looping function.

```
tag @a[tag=!cleanbook,nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:writable_book",tag:{pages:[""]}}]}] add cleanbook
```

So that when a player has a clean book, something happens, for example...

```
execute as @a[tag=cleanbook] run say @a =Clean book=
```

This makes it so that, when a player has an empty book, *"=Clean book="* will be sent in chat, when having a book with anything typed inside it, *"=Clean book="* will stop. It works perfectly, until...
[image: Book and quill screenshot]
When holding the book with cursor, no matter what's inside, it won't be updated and the player will never get a *"cleanbook"* tag (no chat messages at the left). What can I do to take into account a book being held that way, so that the *"cleanbook"* tag updates depending on it's content?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You said "only in survival mode", what happens in Creative? It shouldn't show up in any field I know. You can check with `/data get entity @s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item held in the cursor is not saved to NBT, but it's still a part of the player's inventory, so `/clear` can find it. If you want the same chat spam while cursor-holding the item, throw out the slow NBT method altogether and do this:

```
/execute as @a store result score @s book run clear @s writable_book{pages:[""]} 0
```

Of course, you will need to add a scoreboard objective for this (`book` in this example). When a player's `book` score is 1, that player has a book in their inventory or cursor. This will not work in creative mode, but will in survival/adventure.

---

If you want something *different* to happen when you click on the book, you can take advantage of this NBT vs clear disparity. Just add this command in addition to the one above:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[scores={book=1},nbt={Inventory:[{tag:{pages:[""]}}]}] book 2
```

Now a score of 0 means no book, a score of 1 means the book is in the cursor, and a score of 2 means the book is in an inventory slot.